# Vue.js $emit event from parent and receive it on a component (child)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't seem to get this working!

I have added the `$emit` code to my click event to emit a custom event.

```
<h2 class="form_section--header">Business Hours - <a href="javascript:void(0)" v-on:click="$emit('addBusinessHours', null)">Add New</a></h2>
```

I then listen for this event on my component within the same Vue application, I do this on the template, I would much rather do this within the code:

```
<business-hours :injected-data="hours" :injected-days="data.days[0]" v-on:addBusinessHours="test()">
```

Not sure if this will affect it, but my `business-hours` component is within another component.

Comment: Generally you should not use events to pass something to child components. But if you must do it, you can either use $refs to access the child directly or you can use this.$root.$emit and this.$root.$on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you using a separate class in order to emit events from components.

First create your Event class, as an example, I'm calling EventBus.

```
/* Events.js */
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

Then you import to the component you wish to emit the values from:

```
import {EventBus} from '@/events.js'
```

Then you dispatch the event

```
<h2 class="form_section--header">Business Hours - <a href="javascript:void(0)" v-on:click="emitEvent('addBusinessHours', null)">Add New</a></h2>


emitEvent(name, params) { EventBus.$emit( name , params ); }
```

On your `business-hours` component you import the EventBus and add an event listener to listen to the dispatched event

```
created() { 
   EventBus.$on('addBusinessHours' , () => console.log('Business hours component received event from other component' );
}
```

That should give you a way forward towards sending and receiving events with Vue. 
You can also check this tutorial for reference for a better understanding of how Events works.

https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860

Good luck